# Visual Studio Community 2017 not showing option for EF Code First on Publish

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to use publish asp.net Mvc project with EF and Code First but not able to find any option to use the Code First . [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) 
Am I missing something here in the Publish Profile or any settings missing?
Thanks in advance.
[image: publish]

[image: settings]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run Your visual studio as administrator

2.Go to Publish setting

[image]

3 Select Published Method "Web Deploy"
[image]
[image]

4. Then Flow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis) link.

Comment: Thanks for the Help . Can I use choose File System instead of Web Deploy since I'm targeting a server machine ?

Comment: I think NO. But I think you can deploy local machine then zip manually and upload it to live server.

Comment: Okay I will give a try

Comment: @user2695433 I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: I can see the option to select the DB when selecting the Web Deploy as you said . But what are the server details I shall give , it would test the connection with the server credentials ( url/domain etc), Can I publish this locally at least and then push it manually?

Comment: Yes. Check Update Image.

Comment: Publish failed since the authentication was failed. Can I provide localhost and local credentials here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159150/discussion-between-ashiquzzaman-and-user2695433).